# Pandas join rows of text and output as a new variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given following DF

```
    0
0   Maintain the distance.
1   Ensure it is checked.
2   Inbetween distance must be 0.5.
3   Take extra notes of the distance.
```

Is it possible for Pandas to join all rows, give a new line and return the result as a variable?

Final output:

Variable `n`:

```
Maintain the distance.

Ensure it is checked.

Inbetween distance must be 0.5.

Take extra notes of the distance.
```

I have explored `str.cat()` but seem like the separator do not allow a `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as many `\n` newlines as you like.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(word='a man a plan a canal'.split()))
>>> df
    word
0      a
1    man
2      a
3   plan
4      a
5  canal
>>> 
>>> text = df.word.str.cat(sep='\n\n')
>>> print(text)
a

man

a

plan

a

canal
```